# Get date from datepicker using Ajax with Laravel controller

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, datepicker

i want to get the datepicker value when user selected a date and send that using ajax to a laravel controller. this code is not worked for me..

```
  $.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
  });

  $('#date').datepicker({
  format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
  onSelect: function(date, instance) {
        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: '/process_date',
              data: date,
              success: function(result)
              {
                  console.log(result);
              }
        });  
    }
});
```

here is my route,

```
Route::post('/process_date', 'TimeController@ajaxTime');
```

here is my controller,

```
class TimeController extends Controller
{
  public function ajaxTime(Request $request)
    {
      $data = $request->all(); // This will get all the request data.

      dd($data); // This will dump and die
    }
 }
```

Comment: Which datepicker plugin are you using for `$.datepicker(...)`?

Comment: What exactly is not working ? Is the `onSelect` funcion not executed ? Does the controller action get called ? Is the Date empty ?

Comment: You can format `date` in your controller. It will be easier and better approach.

Comment: @Hashan what is showing when in the browser network output when you select a date.

Comment: @kellymandem nothing shows in browser network when select a date

Comment: @t1gor i am using "bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"

Comment: @Hashan not the console, check your network tab in the developer tools and then see what is being shown there in terms of response headers and request headers.

Comment: @Lapskaus when i selected a date from datepicker nothing shows on console or not working dd()

Comment: I don't see the the `onSelect` in the docs. I guess what you need is the `changeDate` event option. https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changedate

Comment: @t1gor i changed the onSelect to changeDate but nothing happend..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your code to this because I have been reading the [documentation](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changedate) and testing it with some code of my own and this is what I came up with

```
    $('#date').datepicker({
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    }).on('changeDate', function(e) {            
        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: '/process_date',
              data: {
                 date: e.date.toString(),
              },
              success: function(result) {
                  console.log(result);
              },
              error: function (error) {
                  console.log(error);
              }
        });
    })
```

and also change your `TimeController` class from

```
class TimeController extends Controller
{
    public function ajaxTime(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all(); // This will get all the request data.

        dd($data); // This will dump and die
    }
}
```

to

```
class TimeController extends Controller
{
    public function ajaxTime(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->all(); // This will get all the request data.
    }
}
```

to receive better results in your browser console.

Comment: now when i clicked a date lot of data shows in console. how can i extract the selected date?

Comment: @Hashan the reason you are seeing a lot of data in the console is because you doing this `dd($data)` in your controller. I have edited my answer to show you a better way.

Comment: thanks a lot. it works for me. data now showing in browser network tab.